# Except Header in Modal mask

Tags: css, reactjs, modal-dialog, antd

When I make a modal using Ant Design, it makes all the background, including the header, grey like this:

[image: image1]

But I want something like this:

[image: image2]

Here is [a snippet](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oPOLmz?editors=0010) and here is the simplified code:

```
import { Layout, Modal } from "antd";
const { Header } = Layout;

class App = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Header>My header</Header>
    <Modal visible={true}>My modal<Modal>
  </Layout>
);
```

How should I do?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see when viewing the modals code, the `ant-modal-wrap` (dark shadow effect) has a `z-index` set to `1000`.

This means that giving the header a larger `z-index` would make it appear in front of the `ant-modal-wrap`.

Try this:

```
<Header style={{backgroundColor: "red", color: "black", zIndex:1001}}>My header</Header>
```

Of course according to the [documentation](https://ant.design/components/modal/), you can always modify the `z-index` of the modal (default value is 1000 as mentioned above) using the `zIndex` property. You can then adjust both to your liking, the important thing being that the headers `z-index` should be larger, since you want that to appear on top.

Comment: I thought of that, but I reckon the `Header`'s height is dynamic according to the viewport.

Comment: This is not affected by the height of the header, if the `z-index` is larger, it will always appear on top of the overlay, having its original color.

Comment: Oh I get it, I conflated the `top` property with the `zIndex`. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

From the [API](https://ant.design/components/modal/) documentation

> `maskStyle`    Style for modal's mask element.

You can use the `maskStyle` property to adjust the background, e.g.

```
<Modal maskStyle={{backgroundColor: "inherit"}} visible={true}>
   My modal
</Modal>
```

If you however want to keep the background and not overlay the header:

```
<Modal maskStyle={{top: "90px"}} visible={true}>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as I said to the other person, the Header's height is dynamic.